# Replacement has [x] rows, data has [y] when using scale_color_manual

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, aes, scale-color-manual

I am making a plot using ggplot2 n R 3.2.3, with a template that I've been using for long time successfully. I am now getting the same error as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145533/r-message-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) (`replacement has %d rows, data has %d`).

The only difference from the other times I used it is that I'm making the plot using the R kernel of Jupyter Notebook.

Commenting each line at once I reduced the ones responsible for the error to these:

```
P1 <- ggplot(data=x, aes(x=Lf_per_tree, y=Section, fill=Section, col=Section)) +
geom_jitter() +
scale_fill_manual("", values=Colors) +
scale_color_manual("", values=Colors)
```

If I remove the `scale_color` functions, the plot works just fine, so it must be those. Since I used them many times within my template though, I suspect that something is off between the `x` declared in `data=` and the `Colors` declared in `scale_fill/color`.

This is how `head(x)` looks like:

```
   Lf_per_tree   Section
1            7         A
2            5         B
.....
```

This is how `Colors` looks like:

```
$A
[1] "black"

$B
[1] "#C4B3A2"
.....
```

The `scale_color_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` functions in the plot basically take what is declared in `aes()` within `ggplot()` (column "Section") and convert that into a color using the list `Colors`.

This has always worked until now and I have no clue why. Just by the feels of it, it seems as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145533/r-message-error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y) is very close to mine but I couldn't solve it like they do there.

Anyone knows something about this?

Answer (score 1):

Posting for future readers:

After some tinkering I found out that the issue is the following.

`scale_color_` functions do not want `list()` as input for name conversions, rather they want `character()`.

If you have a list of colors such as mine, you have to `unlist()` it to get it in the right format.